# 90% of students face problems in A, 80%in B, 75%in C and 70% in D. What is the minimum percentage of people facing problems in all the subjects.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The complete question is
In a school , 90% of students face problems in A, 80%in B, 75%in C and 70% in D. What is the minimum percentage of people facing problems in all the subjects.

It looks fairly trivial but I am confused on how to proceed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the school has 20 students, so that we can work with numbers instead of percentages.  Then $18$ are in set $A$, $16$ in $B$, $15$ in $C$, and $14$ in $D$.  One way to solve this is to go through the subjects one by one.

Let's start with $A$ and $B$.  We know that 18 students have problems in $A$, and $16$ students have problems in $B$.  We want to find the *minimum* number who have problems in both subjects.  The minimum occurs when we make the intersection as small as possible, which occurs when there are $14$ students in $A \cap B$, $4$ students in $A \setminus B$, and $2$ students in $B \setminus A$.  Now notice that out of these $20$ students, we only need to worry about the $14$, since they are the only ones who have a chance at being in all four sets.

So we continue with $14$ students in $A \cap B$ and $15$ students in $C$.  By the same type of argument, the minimum number of students in $A \cap B \cap C$ is $9$.  Finally, there are $14$ students in $D$ and $9$ in $A \cap B \cap C$, so the minimum number of students in $A \cap B \cap C \cap D$ is $3$, which is $15$% of the $20$ students.

---

EDIT: Maybe it is easier to look at the percentages *not* in each set.  Then we have $10\%$ not in $A$, $20\%$ not in $B$, $25\%$ not in $C$, and $30\%$ not in $D$.  The intersection is minimized when there is no overlap among the percentages listed above.  In otherwords, the full $10 + 20 + 25 + 30 = 85\%$ are *not* in all four, so that $15\%$ *are* in all four.

---

EDIT 2: To check that the minimum in $A \cap B$ is indeed 14, it may help to look at the following Venn diagram.  Call the intersection "brown".

[image]

There are 18 students in orange + brown, so there are 2 students in blue + white (white is outside both A and B).  There are 16 students in blue + brown, so there are 4 students in orange + white.  Therefore, there are at least 0 students in white, and at most 2 students in white.  If there are 0 students in white, there are 2 in blue, 4 in orange, and 14 in brown.  If there is 1 student in white, there is 1 in blue, 3 in orange, and 15 in brown.  If there are 2 students in white, there are 0 in blue, 2 in orange, and 16 in brown.  So you can see that we *minimize* brown when we choose zero in white.  (By the way, this is the basis of the alternate proof in the first edit.)

Comment: Hi Michael, 
Thanks for the reply. You answer is correct but, could you explain one thing? How did you arrive at A(intersection)B = 14. If I want a min I will just make it zero. What would I violate? Could you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: @Bootstrap Sure.  There are only 2 students not in $A$, and there are only 4 students not in $B$.  The other 14 students must be in $A \cap B$.  If it still isn't quite clear, maybe try drawing a Venn diagram with just $A$ and $B$ (not yet $C$ or $D$).  Try to figure out where the 2 students not in $A$ could go, and figure out where the students not in $B$ could go.  You'll see that there must be $14$ in the intersection.

Comment: @ Michael: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now. Did not realize I could do this piece wise, I was considering all 4 at once and things just got messy.

Comment: @Bootstrap Edited once more to hopefully make it much clearer.

Comment: @ Michael: Thanks a lot. Yes, it is much more clear now.